# Is there a good way to dynamically update site data from the cache?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I've run into a bit of an issue. Here's the problem:

On the website we sell some products and we've recently built out our website using React, Node, and NextJS. We currently store most information like product prices in our cache and just read through the cache to display the current price, etc. Whenever we update our prices the updates are not rendering to the website despite the fact they ARE getting put into the cache. For example when changing a product from $9 to $10 the cache updates to say it costs $10, but the user never gets updated - the website says the product still costs $9 until we redeploy.

Is there a way to have the user get the new update on a refresh rather than us having to redeploy the production build? I've currently tried reading in a script (doesn't work cause we're using SSR to serve the information to the components. They never get the cache that's input in the script), and various packages to help clear the cache, but none have worked. We currently just have the cache stored in a cache.js file and are importing it into whatever file needs it.

Comment: I guess the problem is server-side rendering. Are you using any kind of hooks to redeploy?

Comment: *"We currently just have the cache stored in a cache.js file and are importing it into whatever file needs it."* That's not a cache. That's a data file.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, I know. I didn't make the system, but I've inherited it. It's similar to how they did their previous site with Angular and it works for those websites, so I figure there's gotta be a way to do it with React.

Comment: Well, I came to the question expecting to answer a question about cache invalidation, but find it's just a file that gets deployed like any other and has nothing to do with caching at all. Kind of a bait and switch deal.

Comment: @BertKrakowski We switched to SSR for SEO purposes. I'm not totally sure, honestly. I remember hearing they had some webhooks implemented but not fully.

Comment: @HereticMonkey sorry about that - not my intention at all. I'm still relatively new to this and kind of just figuring it out.

Comment: @NicholasN Briefly: when the content has changed your backend should send info about it to the build service (like e.g. Buildkite), then it should trigger the automated redeploy.
Do you have a custom backend or you are using an external solution? If it is the latter, it is possible there are already ready hooks to which you just need to plug in

Comment: Sounds like `cache.js` is just your database). What is the purpose to store stuff like price inside of the file? What do you want to achieve doing that?